# Django: How to create an user and set its related field

Tags: python, django

I've extended the user data using another model (OneToOne relation) and when a user is created, its profile is also created. I'd like to update the field **mailing** when the user is created without a query.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user         = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mailing      = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    ...   
     if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        user.mailing = profile_form.cleaned_data['mailing']
        user.save() #The user is created but mailing is not set
        return redirect('login')
```

**profile_backend.py**

```
class ProfileBackend(ModelBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel._default_manager.select_related('profile').get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I can set the variable taking the user as object but this imply using an extra function.

Answer (score 0):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile_id = uuid.uuid1().hex #for unique id if any
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance,profile_id=profile_id)
    instance.profile.save()
```

This is one of my sample code. This may help you out.

Comment: Same problem, data is not being saved. Is `user.mailing = True` correct or should I actually modify it?